# two checkbox doesn't open in the same time

Tags: html, css, checkbox, click

How I do? e.g. I have two checkbox, both of these boxes can not work. CSS so on, but how do I do?

```
<input id="val1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="val1">Value1</label>
<input id="val2" type="checkbox" />
<label for="val2">Value2</label>
```

Thank you for interest.
Good work..

Comment: I honestly couldn't figure out what you're trying to say or achieve.

Comment: It sounds like he is looking for *radio*, not *checkbox*.

Comment: **checkbox** objects, such as **radio** objects I want to use.

Comment: Rephrase the question in an understandable way and include a fiddle in the question (not in a comment). Specify what the desired functionality is, instead of describing the issue contradictory terms (like being both checkbox and radio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have two controls that cannot be simultaneously selected. In HTML, that would be a radio button, not a checkbox. You would use the same `name` attribute to make them a functional group:

```
<input id="val1" type="radio" name="foo" />
<label for="val1">Value1</label>
<input id="val2" type="radio" name="foo" />
<label for="val2">Value2</label>
```

Note, however, that once a radio button has been selected by the user, the set of radio buttons cannot be reset to “no selection” state, except via a reset button (which is really a destruction button and should be avoided at almost any cost) or via scripting.

Thus, it is generally useful to include a dummy entry for no selection:

```
<input id="val0" type="radio" name="foo" checked="checked" />
<label for="val0">Not answered yet</label>
<input id="val1" type="radio" name="foo" />
<label for="val1">Value1</label>
<input id="val2" type="radio" name="foo" />
<label for="val2">Value2</label>
```

Comment: @KurtuluşMert, you have not said what the problem is if it is not what was assumed in my answer. Your fiddle has two checkboxes, outside any forms, and positioned outside the viewport. This makes no sense: such checkboxes cannot have any impact in the absence of scripting, and your fiddle has no script.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I did think..
before "Giriş yap" so left click checkbox, after "Üye ol" so right click checkbox.. Are you see? Last checkbox click to opened form over up to first checkbox click to opened other form. Forms may not overlap. I want to block it.. How I do?

Comment: @KurtuluşMert, clarify the question by editing the question, not in comments. Also post a jsfiddle that has `checkbox` replaced by `radio`, since you clearly want the radio button behavior.